# Hierarchically printing contents of a folder structure read from a file

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I have a CSV file that has two columns `url` and `folder`. I need to read each row from CSV and end up with some kind of stucture(maybe a dictionary) that organizes each url according to its full folder path. The folder column will be the full folder path of the URL in the format of `Parent/Child/Subchild`.  I will then need to loop through this structure and print all urls organized by folder.

Lets say that I have the following entries in my CSV file:

```
url,folder
www.facebook.com, Entertainment/Social Media
www.espn.com, Entertainment/Sports
www.espndeportes.espn.com, Entertainment/Sports/Spanish
www.instagram.com, Entertainment
```

I expect an output like so:

```
### Entertainment ###
    ### Social Media ###
        www.facebook.com
    ### Social Media ###
    ### Sports ###
        ### Spanish ###
        www.espndeportes.espn.com
        ### Spanish ###
        www.espn.com
    ### Sports ###
    www.instagram.com
### Entertainment ###
```

I know how to read the CSV file, I just don't know how to properly structure the data and how to loop through it to end up with the desired result, please help. The script should allow for any level of nesting necessary. Indentation is not important.

**UPDATE**

I want to add a third header to my CSV file called `friendly`. The value of this column should be printed on the same line as the url separated by " - ":

A new sample CSV file would be:

```
friendly,url,folder
CUCM - North,cucm-n.acme.com,ACME/CUCM/North
CUCM - PUB,cucm-pub.acme.com,ACME/CUCM
UCCX - South,uccx-south.acme.com,ACME/UCCX/South
UCCX - North,uccx-north.acme.com,ACME/UCCX/North
UCCX - PUB,uccx-pub.acme.com,ACME/UCCX
Database,db.acme.com,ACME
CUCM - North2,cucm-n2.acme.com,ACME/CUCM/North
```

A portion of the printout would be as follows:

```
### ACME ###
### CUCM ###
CUCM - PUB - cucm-pub.acme.com
### CUCM ###
Database - db.acme.com
### ACME ###
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right, just read the file into a nested dict, one level per directory, and then walk it to print out. `tree_t` should probably just be a class, but this was simpler.

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

reader = csv.DictReader(file) # or whatever your file is

node = namedtuple('node', ['subtrees', 'files'])
tree_t = lambda: node(defaultdict(tree_t), [])

tree = tree_t()
for entry in reader:
    t_cur = tree
    for level in entry['folder'].split('/'):
        t_cur = t_cur.subtrees[level]
    t_cur.files.append('{friendly} - {url}'.format(**entry))

def tree2str(tree):
    s = ''
    for name, subtree in tree.subtrees.items():
        s += ('###{name}###\n'
              '{child}\n'
              '###{name}###\n').format(name=name, child=tree2str(subtree))

    s += '\n'.join(tree.files)

    return s

print(tree2str(tree))
```

Comment: indenting is kind of funky, can you please let me know what's going on? I edited my original post with the print output. Additionally, pleases see updates

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit, hopefully it's clearer. I don't quite understand your update though, a sample csv might help

Comment: I've updated my update. Hopefully it's clear now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, answered update also. I just formatted that part as it's added to the tree, since it doesn't seem to need any other processing

Comment: Thank you. I tested the code and I am getting the following error:

 `t_cur = t_cur.subtree[level]
AttributeError: 'node' object has no attribute 'subtree'` 

Any suggestions?

Comment: yeah, I forgot a letter and didn't run it, it should have been `subtrees`. Fixed now

Comment: my requirements have changed a bit. Are you able to help me to expand the functionality of this code to achieve my new requirements listed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436822/how-to-turn-bookmarks-read-from-csv-into-an-html-bookmarks-input-file?noredirect=1#comment101351286_57436822)?

Comment: That's just changing the formatting string here. Work through it, see if you can figure it out. You're just expecting someone to write your entire program at this point...

Comment: Fair enough. I've been trying to understand the code that you provided me so that I can adjust it. But I'm having some problems understanding portions of it. For example, why is `tree_t` being defined and passed to `defaultdict` in this line: `tree_t = lambda: node(defaultdict(tree_t), [])`

Comment: It's a recursive structure, so it's defined in terms of itself. `defaultdict` calls the function you give it to create values when you try to access an empty value, so in effect it makes a new version of itself whenever you add in a new level. This probably would have been clearer if it was a class, but you can still think of it as a class that has a member of its own type

Comment: thanks for all the help. The last part that I am having issues with is the proper indentation of my folders. If you can, can you please check out my new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512098/indenting-the-contents-of-each-level-of-a-nested-dictionary) and provide any help.