# How to read Bookmarks from CSV into an HTML Bookmarks input file?

Tags: html, python-3.x, csv

I have a need to bulk import bookmarks into different web browsers. Bookmarks will originally by stored in a CSV file and upon processing, they should be turned into an HTML file that can be uploaded to any web browser.
My solution needs to be platform agnostic.

A sample csv file is as follows:

```
friendly,url,folder
CUCM - North,cucm-n.acme.com,ACME/CUCM/North
CUCM - PUB,cucm-pub.acme.com,ACME/CUCM
UCCX - South,uccx-south.acme.com,ACME/UCCX/South
UCCX - North,uccx-north.acme.com,ACME/UCCX/North
UCCX - PUB,uccx-pub.acme.com,ACME/UCCX
Database,db.acme.com,ACME
CUCM - North2,cucm-n2.acme.com,ACME/CUCM/North
```

The resulting HTML file would look like so:

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true">Bookmarks bar</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><H3>ACME</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3>CUCM</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3>North</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://cucm-n.acme.com/">CUCM - North</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://cucm-n2.acme.com/">CUCM - North2</A>
                </DL><p>
                <DT><A HREF="http://cucm-pub.acme.com/">CUCM - PUB</A>
            </DL><p>
            <DT><H3>UCCX</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3>South</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://uccx-south.acme/">UCCX - South</A>
                </DL><p>
                <DT><H3>North</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://uccx-north.acme/">UCCX - North</A>
                </DL><p>
                <DT><A HREF="http://uccx-pub.acme.com/">UCCX - PUB</A>
            </DL><p>
            <DT><A HREF="http://db.acme.com/">Database</A>
        </DL><p>
    </DL><p>
</DL><p>
```

My script so far is as follows:

```
import csv

bookmarks_spreadsheet = filedialog.askopenfilename()

reader = csv.DictReader(open(bookmarks_spreadsheet, 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig"))
for row in reader:
    bookmarks.append(row)
    url = row['url']
    friendly = row['friendly']
    folder = row['folder']
```

Please help with the remaining code needed to generate my expected HTML file.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this tool: https://sometools.netlify.com/ I did use it and works fine for what I wanted.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)